# Mix textview created in code with storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextview

In order to have placeholders for textviews--to clean up my UI--I have downloaded a [category](https://github.com/devxoul/UITextView-Placeholder) that supports a placeholder in a text view with one line of code after you create the textview in code as follows:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.placeholder = @"How are you?";
textView.placeholderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // optional
```

However, I already have a lot of textviews created in storyboard throughout the app.  The category requires you to create the textview in code as above--something I have not previously done.  And right now my textviews are wired up using storyboard as outlets and methods to retrieve and save data.

Is there anyway to preserve all the textviews I currently have in storyboard and still use the category to provide placeholders?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions:

*First:*

- Create your own `UITextView` inheritor
- Add this code to `awakeFromNib` (do not forget to call super!!)
- Set your new class as custom class for this view in storyboard (http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Storyboard-Change-View-Controller-Class.jpg). You can do it for view too, not only for controller.

*Second*

- Create custom controller (you probably did it anyway)
- In `viewDidLoad:` either iterate though your views to find all text fields or use `IBOutlet` to inject them to controller as properties. Once you have pointer to your view, simply run your code.

Comment: I don't understand either solution.  There is a custom class for the view controller.  However, I don't know how to access a textview created in storyboard from code in that view controller although I get you put it in viewdidload.  Is there a way to give the textview a name?

Comment: You need to use Outlets:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html